# iOS: destroy subviews in viewDidDisappear?

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting

I have a `UINavigationController` with a `UIViewController` pushed onto it. In my `viewController`s `view`, I have two subview `UIScrollView`s. I recreate these `scrollview`s every time in the `viewWillAppear` method in my `viewController` and add them as subviews to my viewcontroller's view. I am using ARC, should I be destroying the two scroll views in `viewDidDisappear` method? What is better practice for memory usage.

EDIT: I did some investigation, and without removing the scroll views and setting them to nil in the `viewDidDisappear` method, they are not released. The viewcontroller's view gets an increasing number of subviews as `viewWillAppear` is called. As I mentioned in the comments, I never deallocate my main viewcontroller. It always stays on the navigation controller's stack. Why must I manually release the scroll views?

Comment: Just set the pointer to your subview to `nil`. ARC will take care of it, that's the idea behind ARC.

Comment: Sorry, that's what I meant. I'm doing that, and I am wondering if its even necessary.

Comment: It's necessary if your app is a heavy resources-eater. Usually when you're popping a view, you'll not be seeing any subviews, so there's no point to have them in memory. If you'll need see those things again, reallocate them. It's a good practice (they'll be deallocated anyway if your superview ever gets deallocated).

Comment: It depends. Please show the code where you allocate the scroll views. You wouldn't destroy them anyway, just remove from super view.

Comment: every time when the viewwillappear called you can judge whether the scroll is nil, if not you don't need to rebuild it. but if you really want to remove it ,I think you can set it nil or remove it from its superview

Comment: Would I just do a simple if statement? if (scroll == nil) { [self:rebuild scroll] }

Answer (score 1):

It may not be necessary to do anything at all. If your UIViewController is removed from the screen and is then being deallocated, it will automatically deallocate its view hierarchy (including subviews you have added). An easy way to check for this is to override the `dealloc` methods of the classes you're interested in (using an ObjC Category method added to the class), and log a message to indicate they've been removed.

Comment: He's using ARC. Can you override `dealloc` anyway? I mean... will he be able to call it?

Comment: You never call `dealloc` yourself, and yes you can override it. ARC will call it for him.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know it would be called automatically. For some reason I thought there was another hidden method to deallocate.

Comment: Just to be slightly more specific: when the view controller is deallocated, it will *release* its view hierarchy. That will deallocate the view hierarchy if-and-only-if no other retains are on those views (not counting the controller's ivars, since they're released too). This is the normal case, so generally, @Idles is completely correct. But if other pieces of the system have retains on the view controller's views (this is generally bad practice), then the views will not be deallocated.

Comment: My viewcontroller is never removed. I push other viewcontrollers on top, but the main viewcontroller is never removed.